# what is %(AdditionalDependencies) macro?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

At projectProperties->linker->Additional Dependencies i have following line:

```
kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

What is %(AdditionalDependencies) ? Where i can define it?

Comment: The display of this property was designed to maximize confusion.  Just plain %(AdditionalDependencies) does the exact same thing.  Inherit properties from a project property sheet.  The "Core Windows Libraries" property sheet in this case.  The $(Inherit) macro in previous versions of VS did the same thing.  Use View + (Other Windows) + Property Manager to see it.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio lets you use [Property Sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx).  Your project can have various configurations, which can have properties from any/all of your Property Sheets, plus locally defined properties.

For example, on one recent project, I created the following property sheets: 1) common, 2) 32 bit, 3) 64 bit, 4) Debug, 5) Release.

A given configuration (e.g., 32-bit English Release build) would have a combination of those: 1 + 2 + 5 + property-specific "English" definition.

The macro you're seeing is used for "do I use properties from the property sheet plus additional properties" or "do I override the properties entirely and ignore the property sheets."

It's kind of a trick to set these up correct the first time, but it really simplifies maintaining multiple project settings.