# How to avoid linking unnecessary windows libraries when building through CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have noticed that when building with CMake on Windows, it automatically adds some unnecessary libraries for all projects.

Example (partial ldd output):

```
$ ldd ./build/release/bin/program.exe
        ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffee1180000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffee0d00000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffede3b0000)
        msvcrt.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffee0120000)
        libstdc++-6.dll => /c/mingw64/mingw64/bin/libstdc++-6.dll (0x6fc40000)
        mcfgthread-12.dll => /c/mingw64/mingw64/bin/mcfgthread-12.dll (0x6c080000)
        libboost_filesystem-mt.dll => /c/mingw64/mingw64/bin/libboost_filesystem-mt.dll (0x638c0000)
        ADVAPI32.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/ADVAPI32.dll (0x7ffedf230000)
        sechost.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/sechost.dll (0x7ffee0ef0000)
        RPCRT4.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/RPCRT4.dll (0x7ffee0230000)
        libboost_program_options-mt.dll => /c/mingw64/mingw64/bin/libboost_program_options-mt.dll (0x678c0000)
        libgcc_s_seh-1.dll => /c/mingw64/mingw64/bin/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (0x61440000)
        WS2_32.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/WS2_32.dll (0x7ffee01c0000)
        WSOCK32.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/WSOCK32.dll (0x7ffedbfd0000)
        libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll => /c/mingw64/mingw64/bin/libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll (0x67e00000)
        USER32.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/USER32.dll (0x7ffee0350000)
        win32u.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/win32u.dll (0x7ffede190000)
        GDI32.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/GDI32.dll (0x7ffee04f0000)
        gdi32full.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/gdi32full.dll (0x7ffede1c0000)
        msvcp_win.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/msvcp_win.dll (0x7ffedee30000)
        ucrtbase.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/ucrtbase.dll (0x7ffedeed0000)
        libssl-1_1-x64.dll => /c/mingw64/mingw64/bin/libssl-1_1-x64.dll (0x6d480000)
```

The default values of both `CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` and `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` for my compiler (MinGW-w64 with MCF threads and SEH) are `-lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32`. As for console application, I'm pretty sure it does not need `gdi32` and many others. **Is there any way to disable linking these libraries, without touching `CMAKE_` variables?** I would like to avoid touching any variables in the era of modern CMake and target-based recipes.

Comment: `ldd` on Windows? Where'd you get that?

Comment: Binutils come with any Windows GCC distribution. Some other tools come with Git Bash or MSYS shell.

Comment: `ldd` is not part of binutils. `ld` is part of binutils, `ldd` is part of glibc. But I know you don't have glibc installed because you're on Windows.

Comment: Ok, bad naming then. Anyway any Windows GCC distro packages a lot of tools (100+ executables in `mingw64/bin`). `which ldd` reports `/usr/bin/ldd` so this one comes from Git Bash.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400536/why-cmake-adds-unnecessary-libraries-to-visual-studio-project