# CMake'ifying a Boost Jam file: Windows library names

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, ole, dbgeng

I'm trying to "De-boostify" one of the Boost libraries, which is more or less stand-alone anyway. (It is Antony Polukhin's wonderful [`stacktrace` library][1]; which gives you easy access to stacktraces, with names and line numbers and no hassle. But that's beside the point.)

Now, Boost uses its own Build System, [B2][2], which uses "Jam files" for configuration; so I'm trying to migrate this library's Jam file into a `CMakeLists.txt`.

Specifically, I need to convert dependencies expressed in B2 terms into `find_package()` commands, or at worst, look for some DLLs on my own. Specifically, it seems I need the libraries which Boost refers to as: `Dbgeng` and `ole32`.

What would be the CMake equivalent of depending on these two?

Note: I know almost nothing about Windows development.

Comment: ole32 should be standard in Win. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400536/why-cmake-adds-unnecessary-libraries-to-visual-studio-project

Comment: @SergeyA: Do you mean that I don't have to mention this dependency and it would be added by default?